# Update multiple records with Entity Framwork

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am wondering what the best way to update multiple records with Entity Framework is.
This is how I normally do it, and it does work:

```
    private static void SetNcprpCodesAsComplete(string[] ncprpCodes)
    {
        using (var ent = new Data.Entities())
        {
            var query = from ba in ent.BuildingAssessments
                        where ncprpCodes.Contains(ba.NcprpCode)
                        select ba.TabletAssessment;
            foreach (var ta in query) ta.Complete = true;
            ent.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

This query should also work (is one better than the other)

```
      var query = from ta in ent.TabletAssessments
                  where ncprpCodes.Contains(ta.BuildingAssessment.NcprpCode)
                  select ta;
```

Another way could be looping through the `string[]`, attaching and updating. Is it possible to attach when doing a multi table query like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the usual way how to update properties in EF, and in your case, I'd say it seems the only proper way. You can surely attach and update - but then you'll loose all other properties in your entity. To sum up - if you'd need to update one property in entities, you'll need to do SELECT (your query), modify entities (foreach) and then do UPDATE (SaveChanges).

Comment: Yes, this is the best I have been able to come up with.
It is not quite as elegant as a SQL update, but maybe thinking in terms of SQL when using EF is my problem.

Comment: Yes, I can understand that :) It's not specific to EF, but to ORM in general - you don't work with rows and tables, you work with objects (entities) and their properties. Frankly, you can mix both ways, but only when you *exactly* know why and what you're doing, what impact such update would have on your context(s) and usually in very specific scenarios.

Answer (score 5):

If you have X rows, you're going to issue X update statements to the database behind the scenes. You're also going to be loading up all those records in the first place. This could be a problem if you have say a million rows to update. So if performance becomes a problem, you could go the SQL route in this case. Especially since it seems the results are only being used for this update in your example

```
string sql = @"update MyTable set MyField={0} where MyCrit={1}";
List<Object> sqlParamsList = new List<object>();
sqlParamsList.Add(value1);
sqlParamsList.Add(value2);

ent.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, sqlParamsList.ToArray());
```

Note that this code is *not* vulnerable to sql injection attacks. I wanted to show the syntax for sql parameters using an object array.

I had a situation like this and using the method above got an order of magnitude performance improvement over the non-SQL way with only ~2000 records.